# Using $trunc or $round in Mongodb does not guarantee 2 decimal places

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I have something like this.

```js
"Amount": { "value": { "$trunc": [ "$Amount", 2] }
```

When my Amount field is 244.50, it omits 0 and makes it 244.5
How do I ensure that it is 244.50 by using $trunc or $round. It is ok if the value is in string but it has to have 0 at the end. Please help.

Comment: You need to be looking at number formatting for that. $trunc simply discards unneeded precision.

Comment: I looked at documentation and can't find number formatting. Can you point me there?

Comment: I don't know whether MongoDB provides this on the server side.

Comment: I was expecting this to be part of aggregate pipelines where we can simply output number with two decimals. I have these pipelines feeding directly to api with no control over data (or configuration of it).

Answer (score 2):

So I went ahead and resolved it and hopefully it will be helpful for someone in the future. Here is my answer. You can use $trunc or $round.

```js
{ "Amount": { "value": { "$toString": { "$trunc": [ {"$toDecimal": "$Amount"}, 2] } } }
```

It is important to note that in my case, I can have string as final output as I am using this value to populate for printing in a statement. I don't plan to use it for calculation purpose (in which case, you would not need this in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

Use Decimal128:

```
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.foo.insert({a:NumberDecimal('1.2020')})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.foo.aggregate([{$project:{v:{$trunc:['$a',2]}}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f36d9ccad0dd0c8ef1cc0e2"), "v" : NumberDecimal("1.20") }
```

Comment: Thank D.SM. It definitely pointed me to think differently as it was clear that there is no straightforward way to resolve it.